# Bootstrapping a simple function in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, random, resampling

I have a simple function called `foo`. To bootstrap it (randomly shuffle it), I use library `boot` using the instructions [HERE](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-generate-bootstrap-statistics-in-r/). But it looks like I have an indexing problem because I get the following error:

`number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`, is this fixable?

```
library(boot)
foo <- function(X) {
  X <- as.matrix(X)
 tab <- table(row(X), factor(X, levels = sort(unique(as.vector(X)))))
 w <- diag(ncol(tab))
 rosum <- rowSums(tab)
 obs_oc <- tab * (t(w %*% t(tab)) - 1)
 obs_c <- colSums(obs_oc)
 max_oc <- tab * (rosum - 1)
 max_c <- colSums(max_oc)
 SA <- obs_c / max_c
 h <- names(SA)
 h[is.na(h)] <- "NA"
 setNames(SA, h)
 }  
 # EXAMPLE OF USE:
 dat <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = c(2,1, 3, 4))

 foo(dat)

 # Tried the following to bootstrap it:

 boot_fun <- function(data, i){

  resample <- data[i, ,drop = FALSE]
  foo(resample)
 }

boot::boot(
 data = dat,
statistic = boot_fun,
R = 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you may do boostrapping using `replicate` and don't need `boot` for bootstrapping. However, your function might yield different results as expected.

```
set.seed(42)
R <- 5
replicate(R, foo(dat[sample(1:nrow(dat), replace=TRUE),]))
# [[1]]
# 1 2 
# 0 0 
# 
# [[2]]
# 1 2 4 
# 0 0 1 
# 
# [[3]]
# 1 2 3 4 
# 0 0 1 1 
# 
# [[4]]
# 1 2 3 4 
# 0 0 1 1 
# 
# [[5]]
# 1 2 4 
# 0 0 1
```

As you see, the result may have different lengths which causes the error.

I'm not absolutely sure what you're after, but I think the second line is the crux of the matter. `table` doesn't get the levels that don't exist. You could try to use a `factor` and define a complete set of `levels=`. I'm not sure, though, which the unique levels of your real data are, I just used the row numbers. But this might help you.

```
foo <- function(X) {
  X <- as.matrix(X)
  # tab <- table(row(X), unlist(X))  ## NB: unlisting a matrix is pointless, use as.vector()
  tab <- table(row(X), factor(as.vector(X), levels=1:nrow(X)))
  w <- diag(ncol(tab))
  rosum <- rowSums(tab)
  obs_oc <- tab * (t(w %*% t(tab)) - 1)
  obs_c <- colSums(obs_oc)
  max_oc <- tab * (rosum - 1)
  max_c <- colSums(max_oc)
  SA <- obs_c / max_c
  h <- names(SA)
  h[is.na(h)] <- "NA"
  setNames(SA, h)
}  

set.seed(42)
replicate(5, foo(dat[sample(1:nrow(dat), replace=TRUE),]))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# 1    0    0    0    0    0
# 2    0    0    0    0    0
# 3  NaN  NaN    1    1  NaN
# 4  NaN    1    1    1    1
```

Or using `boot`.

```
set.seed(42)
boot::boot(
  data = dat,
  statistic = boot_fun,
  R = 200)
# ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
# 
# 
# Call:
#   boot::boot(data = dat, statistic = boot_fun, R = 200)
# 
# 
# Bootstrap Statistics :
#     original  bias    std. error
# t1*        0       0           0
# t2*        0       0           0
# t3*        1       0           0
# t4*        1       0           0
```

Comment: Many thanks! My goal is to compute the bottstrapped CIs from the `replicate`s. But before that, I think changing the second line is not the solution. For example, please use the following small but real data.frame: `DAT <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/X.csv", row.names = 1)`. Now if we do `foo(DAT)` with your suggested solution, it returns all `NaN`. But if you use my own `unlist(X)`, `foo` correctly returns: `EFL       ESL 
0.8235294 0.0000000`. Do you see the point?

Comment: @rnorouzian Yeah, because it yealds probably the wrong levels inside. However my point is `identical(unlist(as.matrix(DAT)), as.matrix(DAT))`, so unlist has no effect at all on a matrix whereas `as.vector` has.

Comment: I see thanks! Given all of that, would you mind updating your answer then? Again, my goal is to use `quantile` at the end, highly appreciated!

Comment: Update: I changed that line to: `table(row(X), factor(X, levels = sort(unique(as.vector(X)))))`